# ERL: Modify mnesia configuration from erl command line (ejabberd cluster)

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I am using ejabberd with mnesia. I want to add another node to our cluster, and at the same time modify the default mnesia configuration properties before starting ejabberd:

```
dump_log_write_threshold = 10000
dc_dump_limit = 10
```

I am using this command:

```
erl -sname ejabberd@node2 -mnesia dump_log_write_threshold 10000 \
-mnesia dc_dump_limit 10 -mnesia dir '"/var/lib/ejabberd"' \
-mnesia extra_db_nodes "['ejabberd@node1']" -s mnesia
```

But on starting ejabberd the values have reverted to default. I don't have much experience in erl or mnesia so I'm probably doing something obviously wrong :-)

Comment: I would guess that ejaberrd reads the configuration from a file. Can you post how the main ejaberrd node is being started? Or do `ps aux` to look for erl nodes? Arguments used to start the ejaberrd node should contain an explicit instruction to use a specific configuration file. I don't know much about ejaberrd but this is how usually Erlang nodes are being started.